# How to test game center without registering an app?

Tags: ios, game-center

I need to test game center for an app that is still not ready for deployment. The book I'm following says that I need to register the app in iTunes Connect. But I don't want to release that app yet. Is there a workaround to be able to use game center even without submitting the app to the app store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't submit your first binary to iTunes Connect and get it approved, your app will not be shown on the App Store.

You can create your app record in iTunes Connect without worry, because it doesn't mean your app will be released. The information you submit can be changed as often you need as long as your app is in the state **Prepare for submission**. Once your app is approved, you need to submit a new version if you want to change some informations.

Game Center isn't the only service which require you to register an app on iTunes connect, you need to create a record too if you want to test in-app purchases.